# PUSH State showing error in AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, seo, pushstate

I was using the **PUSH state** in my site for **SEO**,

When i use **PUSH state**, It shows these Error which i have displayed below.

```
Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module projectApp due to:
```

**Here is my AngularJS Code**

```
<script>
var countryApp = angular.module('projectApp', ['ngSanitize']);
countryApp.config(['$location',function ($location) {
$location.html5Mode(true);
}]);
</script>
```

Comment: Specifies more code here for better understanding like give html page code

Comment: @NiraleePatel : This much code is enough for this question...

Comment: can you add myApp="projectApp" in page?

Comment: @NiraleePatel: can you Explain it clearly , what you are trying to say..

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to inject a service into a config function. And it it not possible. Only constant and providers can be injected. Instead, inject $locationProvider.

```
countryApp.config(['$locationProvider',function ($locationProvider) {
   $locationProvider.html5Mode = true;
}]);
```

Comment: Did you injected locationProvider ? I updated by response because it was wrong...

Comment: Actually i was new to AngularJS,SO How can i inject the location provider, I f you have any demo that will useful for me.

Comment: This Example helps fine, Thanks :)

Comment: Do not hesitate do validate the answer if is the right one :)

Comment: Here the contents are not showing in the view source by using angularJs, But In your example content was given directly.